# appcelerator - xlarge images go in which folder?

Tags: image, screen, appcelerator

According to the [density specific page](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Using_density-specific_resources_on_Android) for appcelerator 3.X, there are three density screens, high, medium, and low.

According to the actual android docs [*that the density specific page itself links to*](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), there are four screens, small, medium, large and xlarge.

If i have xlarge images, what is the name of the appcelerator folder I am meant to put them into so that the appcelerator app will use them when the app is loaded into a tablet or other, xlarge type, device?

Answer (score 0):

image.jpg, image@2X.jpg, image@3X.jpg is for use in iOS only as far as I can tell.

In Android there are specific folders to put these files so they are served up based on the Android devices screen density profile.

Put these in: /Resources/android/images and in there you should have all of these folders, if not create them:

[image]

Anything that is in /android will not be included in an iOS build and vice versa.